# How disable some product features on woocomerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin

My website is a product review website. I'm using woocomerce in order to store all products and let user be able to search them by category and attributes.

Due this, I would like to remove some unnecessary options from my wordpress admin like inventory and shipping.

.[image]

How can I disable those functions from my wordpress??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below function in your function file

```
/*For remove tab from product tab*/
function remove_linked_products($tabs){
    unset($tabs['inventory']);
    unset($tabs['shipping']);
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);

/*Remove Virtual and Downloadeble checkbox*/
function remove_product_type_options( $options ) {
    unset( $options['virtual'] );
    unset( $options['downloadable'] );
    return $options;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'remove_product_type_options' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you give users access to the backpanel? Shipping and inventory are not attributes that really distract users on a frontend I guess. A quick solution would be hiding individual meta data with CSS.

```
.sku_wrapper{display: none;}
```

You could also use this to hide parts in your admin panel (example the product data top table row with product type, virtual and downloadable)

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_styles');
function my_custom_admin_styles() {
// just add the css selectors below to hide each field as required
echo '<style>
#woocommerce-product-data .hndle {
display: none; }
</style>';
}
```